# How to output different value types when the field is of a particular type in PHP script?

Tags: php

I'm beginning to understand php as I write more code and I just came across an issue of trying to output data as a JSON where the field ID is specified as a `varchar` type, but the stored values in it are mixed strings, ints, and doubles.

Here's what my database table looks like:

```
 map_type      map_value  
 -----------------------------
 link          www.google.com
 zoom          18
 lat           32.91
 long          -117.1
```

The fields `map_type` and `map_value` are of type `varchar`.

I wrote some simple code to output the data:

```
$sql = "select map_type, map_value from table";

$q = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$jsonData = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $jsonData[$row['map_type']] = $row['map_value'];
}

echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

And get the output:

```
{
    "link": "www.google.com",
    "zoom": "8",
    "lat": "32.91",
    "long": "-117.1",
}
```

As you can see from `map_value`, there are a mix of strings, int, and doubles.

Upon reading, I know that `mysqli_fetch_assoc` only outputs the data as strings, so I must explicitly specify the return type value of whatever field value I want.

However, how can I specify the different return type **values** even though the field `map_value` is of type `varchar`?

To show what I mean, how can I produce this output where the value of "link" will be a string, the value of "zoom" will be an int, and the values of "lat" and "long" will be doubles

```
{
    "link": "www.google.com",
    "zoom": 8,
    "lat": 32.91,
    "long": -117.1,
}
```

In trying to learn PHP, what I have tried to do so far:

**1.** Add the following code before storing the data in the array:

```
`$row['map_value'] = doubleval($row['map_value']);`.
```

However, as pretty obvious, the value in "link" returns a **0** because it tries to convert the string to a double.

**2.** I also tried to do something like:

```
$row['zoom'] = intval($row['zoom'])
$row['lat'] = doubleval($row['lat'])
$row['long'] = doubleval($row['long'])
```

However, the output is blank, and I came to realize the reason is because that doesn't exist.

How can I solve this dilemma?

Comment: It looks to me like your DB structure is very limited (restricted to a single entry) and possible not what you really want. For example, it does not appear that you can have more than a single map data collection because `map_type` lists variables but the variables should really be the DB table columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`floatval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php).

You can also use `is_numeric()` to test if the string looks like a number.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $value = is_numeric($row['map_value']) ? floatval($row['map_value']) : $row['map_value'];
    $jsonData[$row['map_type']] = $value;
}
```

It's not necessary to choose whether to call `floatval()` or `intval()`. PHP treats floats with no fraction as integers.

Comment: gold!..."the more you know" :)